# In what circumstance file to be read should be put under the bin directory or src directory?

Tags: java

I'm currently using eclipse for developing with Java.
Could anyone explain the reason why files are put under the src directory when using classes like FileReader? and sometimes files have to be put under the bin directory when using methods like getClass().getResourceAsStream("...") for reading images? Are there any alternatives of the method getClass().getResourceAsStream("...") that require files under the src directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You as developer put nothing in the `bin` directory, you only put stuff in `src` and `resources` directories, when the IDE - or any other build tool - builds your project then the generated class files and other resources are put to the bin directory.

Resources which are located in the `bin` directory - and later bundled in your artifacts `.jar` or `.war` etc. - are available in your application's `classpath` and can be accessed by class loaders, which enables classes to be loaded and enables you to find resources using `getClass().gerResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Yet many tutorials use the method getClass().gerResourceAsStream() that reads files from the bin directory, then which method should be used instead?

Comment: _reads files from the bin directory_ that's not correct, it's used to read from the `classpath`, the `bin` directory is not present in the final artifact, for example a `.jar` file (export your project as jar file and open it with your favourite zip file manager, you'll see there is no bin directory!). So you need to know the difference between resources located in your application's `classpath`, for which you can use `gerResourceAsStream()` and resources which are locate on the `filesystem` for which you can use classes from `java.io.*`, where you locate a file is up to you/your requirements.